# Como elimino el valor de un Array de string

Tags: vue.js, foreach

Como elimino el valor de un Array de string, quiero que al escribir en el input lo compare con cada uno de los nombres que hay en el array nombres, estoy empezando con vue, mi lógica era hacer una búsqueda con el forEach pero aun no tengo claro... se los agradezco

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
   import {Ref, ref} from "vue"
   
   interface Iroles{
       nombres: Array<string>
   }

   let roles:Ref<Iroles> = ref({
       nombres: [] 
   });
   let nombre = ref("")

   const addNombres= ()=>{
       roles.value.nombres.push(nombre.value)
       nombre.value=""
   }
   const EliminarUser = ()=>{
       roles.value.nombres.forEach((nom,index)=>{
           if(nombre.value==nom){ 
           }
       })
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero vamos a almacenar en una variable la posicion donde se encuentra el nombre que quieres eliminar, una vez almacenada la posicion podremos utilizar el método `.slice()` para eliminar un valor del Array mediante su posicion.

```
const EliminarUser = () => {
   const pos = roles.value.nombres.findIndex(item => item == nombre.value) // Obtiene la posición del nombre a eliminar.
   
   if(pos >= 0)
      roles.value.nombres.splice(pos, 1) // Elimina 1 elemento desde la posicion indicada
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una manera simple es crear otro `array` y sobrescribir el original, para eso puedes usar `filter`, de esta manera crear un nuevo array donde ningún elemento sea igual a `nombre.value`, así no importa cuantas veces se repita ni en que posición se encuentre

```
const EliminarUser = ()=>{
  roles.value.nombres = roles.value.nombres.filter(a=>nombre.value!=a);      
})
```